# Trying update Jenkins plugin to SimpleBuildStep

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to update Deveo plugin work with Jenkins pipeline but haven't been able to figure out how to access SCM with SimpleBuildStep implemented.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/deveo-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/deveo/plugin/jenkins/DeveoNotifier.java#L131

```
 public void notifyDeveo(AbstractBuild build, BuildListener listener) {
    SCM scm = build.getProject().getScm();
```

So I would like to get for example Git address and revision with plugin.